# gcovr missing .gcda files after executing binary that is linked with a dynamically linked shard object libraries (.so)

Tags: c++, c, .so, gcovr

I am trying to use **gcovr** on my linux project and have no luck getting .gcda files for the dynamic library after executing binary.

I have a project called **projectA** which creates a library called **libprojectA.so** and the unit test project links **libprojectA.so**. The main goal here is that I want to see the code coverage of projectA functions invoked from the unit test binary **UnitTestExecutable**.

I have such a directory structure:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbHSR.png)

This is the steps I followed to call **gcovr**.

1. Build projectA with its Makefile

   - Makefile has "-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fPIC"
   - creates .o and .gcno inside .build directory
   - creates dynamic library libprojectA.so
2. Build unittest

   - Makefile links libprojectA.so
   - Makefile has "-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fPIC"
   - creates .o and .gcno
   - creates binary UnitTestExecutable
3. Execute UnitTestExecutable

   - creates .gcda files inside /unittest/*.gcda
   - it doesn't create *.gcda inside /porjectA/ folder <== this is the problem
4. Call gcovr
   gcovr -v -r /projectA/ --html --html-details -o test-html-details.html --object-directory=/projectA/.build/

   Here it complains that it can't find *.gcda inside /projectA/.build/

Could someone please help ?

Thanks,

Comment: Please don't use screenshots if you have text. Then I'd like to ask you for a [example]. You don't want us to waste time writing all these files by hand, do you? Did you check if the generated gcda files include those for your library units, just in the "wrong" directory?

Comment: If no .gcda for the ProjectA files were created, that would mean that none of libprojecta's code was executed. This can happen e.g. with header-only libraries. If that's not the case, most likely you oversimplified the scenario and accidentally omitted some relevant details.